# Updates changes for nested models

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

ObservableObject doesn't emit change events for nested observables by default. Here a nested settings object within a view model, which is then observed by a view.

In this small example, the `menu` doesn't see changes of `settings` (`enable` value). How to handle this behavior with Combine to propagate changes upwards in `ContentView`?

In other words, how to manually pipe changes from your nested models upwards to the dependent view: maybe introduce property wrappers in between to reduce the boiler plating involved?

```swift
// Wrapper
@propertyWrapper struct UserDefault<T: Codable> {
    private let key: String
    private let defaultValue: T

    init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data else {
                return defaultValue
            }
            let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            return value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
// Values
final class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @UserDefault("itemA", defaultValue: true)
    var itemA: Bool { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }

    @UserDefault("itemB", defaultValue: true)
    var itemB: Bool { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }
    
    @UserDefault("itemC", defaultValue: true)
    var itemC: Bool { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }
}
```

```swift
// Model
struct Language: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var enable: Bool
}

enum Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String {
        switch self {
        case .item(let language): return language.id
        }
    }
    case item(Language)
}

// ModelView
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let settings = UserSettings()
    @Published var menu: [Item]
    var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

    init() {
        menu = [.item(Language(id: "a", enable: settings.itemA)),
                .item(Language(id: "b", enable: settings.itemB)),
                .item(Language(id: "c", enable: settings.itemC))]
    
        settings.objectWillChange.sink { [unowned self] in
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

```swift
// View
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Button("toggle a \(model.settings.itemA.description)") { model.settings.itemA.toggle() }
            Button("toggle b \(model.settings.itemB.description)") { model.settings.itemB.toggle() }
            Button("toggle c \(model.settings.itemC.description)") { model.settings.itemC.toggle() }
        }
        Menu {
            ForEach(model.menu, id:\.self) { content in //// model.menu is not updated
                switch content {
                case let .item(language):
                    if language.enable { // the value doesn't update
                        Button("Item \(language.id)", action: {
                            print(language.id)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        } label: { Text("menu") }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm confused with this `ContentView` - it modifies something but it does not depend on what is modified, so ... what do you expect to be changed? Eg. if I add `Text(model.settings.itemA.description)` in view that it is changed once corresponding button clicked, so observer works.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have updated `ContentView`. In the `ViewModel` the nested `@Published var menu` does not properly follow the changes. How to access the projected value, changed the preference value from our views, and update our view when the preference is changed even from a different place?

Comment: `model.menu` is not updated, because it is not changed anywhere. You change settings object but menu does not depend on it.

Comment: Yes the problem is updating the settings with the menu reflects the changes. How to combine the two with `combine` if it is possible?

Comment: Can you please try to rephrase the last paragraph of your question? It's really hard to understand what you want to do. Do you want to get rid of `willSet { objectWillChange.send() }`? Please try to remove everything from your example that is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @idmean I have updated the question. `willSet` is for `@propertyWrapper`. `@Published var menu: [Item]` doesn't see the `enable` changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, `menu` is only ever set once (on `init`). You want to set `menu` every time the object updates.

To do this, change the `menu` *after* the `settings` object has changed one of the values. Here we receive on the `main` thread, then update the menu with `setMenu()`.

You could also change the `UserSettings` to use `didSet` instead of `willSet`, and then you will no longer require the `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)`. However, this may be a bit counter-intuitive to the meaning of `objectWillChange`.

Code:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let settings = UserSettings()
    @Published private(set) var menu: [Item] = []
    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

    init() {
        setMenu()

        settings.objectWillChange.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).sink { [unowned self] in
            setMenu()
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    private func setMenu() {
        menu = [
            .item(Language(id: "a", enable: settings.itemA)),
            .item(Language(id: "b", enable: settings.itemB)),
            .item(Language(id: "c", enable: settings.itemC))
        ]
    }
}
```

*I did change some things slightly which would be unrelated, such as the access levels. You don't want the user to accidentally edit `menu` directly.*